# Align IFC BIM with photogrametric point cloud in forge viewer

Tags: geolocation, autodesk-forge

I'm loading a bim model (.ifc) and it's corresponding point cloud (generated using photogrametry) in forge viewer. Ifc file has it's own coordinate system but point cloud has real world UTM coordinates. How can I transform ifc file to align it with point cloud to view both of them at the same location in forge viewer. Can I update ifc file with geo location from point cloud included.

Comment: With my tests, the geolocation info. seems not to be supported. I'm double-checking with our engineering team, and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: Hi Jalli, is it possible to provide a none-confidential reproducible IFC model and point cloud model for this case for our investigation on the wishlist item `NWLMV-101`? Currently, I’m discussing with our engineering team about the IFC geolocation support on Forge. If your answer is yes, could you sent it to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com? Thank you!

Comment: Before sending to us, please remove any personal data or confidential information from the rep duck leg models. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current IFC translation doesn't support extracting geolocation from the `IFCSITE` entity. So, I summited an issue list item `NWLMV-101` to our engineering team to allocate time to evaluate IFC geolocation data support.

You're welcome to check the issue update anytime in the future via sending an email with this issue id to Forge support channel. We also will post an announcement on our official website once it released in the future, please stay tuned with us. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once the IFC translation supports extracting geolocation, you can look into this extension, which I found super useful. [GEOLOCATION](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/GeolocationExtension/)

The functions that are pretty useful -

- lmvToLonLat(lmvPoint)
- lonLatToLmv(lonLat)

Cheers!